# Radial css3 animation around a circle

Tags: animation, css

I'm trying to make a div rotating around a circle that is already rotating on himself in css3.

I've tried to use webkit frame, but it don't work well.

Have you some examples of this ?

thanks

Comment: So, for example, you want an image of the Earth in an `<img>` tag to rotate around a point rotating around an image of the Sun?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is 1 great example: [CSS3 Solar System](http://neography.com/experiment/circles/solarsystem/)

The code used is [here](http://neography.com/journal/our-solar-system-in-css3/)